# How do i pass php variable to python script so the python will show the pass variable in browser(xampp)

Tags: python, php

i have a html file `<input type='file' name='loadfile'>` i want to do something like get the file name `$nameOfTheFile = $_FILES["loadfile"]["name"];` when file is loaded and then pass the `filename` to python file called (`formatfiletoJSON.py`) and use python file to read the `filename` and format it become JSON format. And use `json.dumps()` to print out json format in the browser so my Ajax file could get the (`formatfiletoJSON.py`)

The problem: In my `formatfiletoJSON.py` cannot get the filename variable in the browser(`xampp localhost`) it is empty

`print(sys.argv)` <=  this can show in the browser

`filename = sys.argv[1]`
`print(filename)` <= this will not show in the browser and if i execute it in visual studio code terminal it will put this error

```
File "c:\xampp\htdocs\project_real\receivephpvariable.py", line 5, in <module>
    filename = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

what i did:

php file

```
   <?php
if (isset($_FILES["loadfile"]) > 0)
{
$nameOfTheFile = $_FILES["loadfile"]["name"];
$temp = shell_exec("python formatfiletoJSON.py \"$nameOfTheFile\"");
echo $temp;
}
 //html

<form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="loadfile" id="loadfile">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>
```

formatfiletoJSON.py

```
#!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
import json
import sys
print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')

filename = sys.argv[1]


with open(filename +'.py', 'r') as inFile:
     funcs = inFile.read().split('\n\n')
     # print(funcs)
     result = {}
     for elem in funcs:
            if elem.startswith('def'):
             sign, commands = elem.split(':')
             
            #  print(list(map(str.strip, commands.split('\n')))[1:])
             commands = list(map(str.strip, commands.split('\n')))[1:]
             result.update({sign : commands})
    # print(result)

y = json.dumps(result)
print(y)
```

The file name i want to pass to php (function.py)

```
def step35():
    createsd()
    login44()
    delete12()   

def step66():
    autheticate()

def step3():
    send()

def step38():
    sendd()
   

def steppp():
    dsds()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in Python? PHP can read the file itself.

Comment: PHP is executing `receivephpvariable.py`, not `formatfiletoJSON.py`.

Comment: Sorry, there a typo the already rename the receivevariable.py to formatfiletoJSON.py

Comment: My task is to create a website which is using php to load python file and retrieve the string inside the python file and display it in html . So my initial thought was to create a another python file to extract and to do string manipulation inside the python file which is loaded from php and format into JSON so i can ajax it back to php

Comment: maybe first display `$nameOfTheFile` and `"python formatfiletoJSON.py \"$nameOfTheFile\""` to see if you really have any filename. Maybe filename is empty string and it can't get any argument.

Comment: as @Barmar already said - error shows problem with `receivephpvariable.py` but you didn't show this file in question. Maybe you run different code.

Comment: @furas Even if `$fnameOfTheFile` is empty, it should pass an empty argument as `argv[1]`.

Comment: @Gerald Why do you need to use another python file to extract and do string manipulation? PHP can do all those same things. It has `file_get_contents()` to read a file into a string. `explode()` will split it. It has `array_map()`. `json_encode()` is equivalent to `json.dumps()`.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't have PHP for test it and normally I would expect that it runs it with `""` for empty variable but maybe system/shell converts `""` to empty string without `""` and then it may run it as string `python formatfiletoJSON.py` without any arguments. So I'm only guessing that it can run in different way then we expect.